# How do I run python file in mininent and where do I suppose to save the file

Tags: python, networking, configure, mininet, topology

I have python file, I want to run in mininet. But I do not know where to save file and how to run it

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created a node in Mininet, you can treat that node as if it was a virtual machine. You can simply use the name of the node followed by the name of your Python script, for example:

First I create a simple topology

```
sudo mn
```

Then I can call a Python script from inside any of the nodes in the topology:

```
h1 python3 ~/scripts/myscript.py
```

Further reading: http://mininet.org/walkthrough/#python-interpreter